# NHibernate paging for SQL Server 2012

Tags: nhibernate, pagination, sql-server-2012

According to this issue:

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3038

NHibernate should create efficient paging queries for SQL Server 2012.

I have NHibernate 3.3.3GA. I set the dialect in the config file:

```
 <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
```

and while debugging I see that indeed the session factory has `MsSql2012Dialect`.

But still the following code:

```
session.Query<TestEntity>().Skip(1).Take(1).ToList()
```

generates the same T-SQL as the old SQL Server 2008 dialect does:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT TOP (@p0) EntityId1_, Version1_, Name1_, Something1_ 
FROM (select testentity0_.EntityId as EntityId1_, testentity0_.Version as Version1_, testentity0_.Name as Name1_, testentity0_.Something as Something1_, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER(ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
as __hibernate_sort_row from tTestEntity testentity0_) as query
WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > @p1
ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row',N'@p0 int,@p1 int',@p0=1,@p1=1
```

How do I make NHibernate Linq provider to use the paging features of `MsSql2012Dialect` and generate a query with `OFFSET` and `FETCH`?

**Solution:**

Thanks to Diego Mijelshon who led me to the right source code, I managed to implement a quick fix which seems to work fine. We are using it for some months already, no problems yet.

Here is what I did:

I imported the following classes from the NHibernate source into my own library:

https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/967091f5c22a16a576f46144055f78c0f373ffcd/src/NHibernate/SqlCommand/Parser/SqlTokenizerExtensions.cs
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2012Dialect.cs
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/967091f5c22a16a576f46144055f78c0f373ffcd/src/NHibernate/SqlCommand/Parser/SqlTokenizer.cs
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/967091f5c22a16a576f46144055f78c0f373ffcd/src/NHibernate/SqlCommand/Parser/SqlParserUtils.cs
https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/967091f5c22a16a576f46144055f78c0f373ffcd/src/NHibernate/SqlCommand/Parser/SqlToken.cs

As far as I remember, I did some modifications to remove unnecessary bits of code.
In SqlTokenizerExtensions I left only these two extensions:

```
public static bool TryParseUntil(this IEnumerator<SqlToken> tokenEnum, string keyword)
public static bool TryParseUntilFirstMsSqlSelectColumn(this IEnumerator<SqlToken> tokenEnum)
```

SqlTokenizer, SqlToken, SqlParserUtils, MsSql2012Dialect  - no changes.

Then I just set `<property name="dialect">` to the new MsSql2012Dialect  in my config file for NHibernate, and now my paging queries are clean and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at NH-3038, you'll see that it's fixed in master/vNext. That means NH4.

You can still get the updated dialect from https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Dialect/MsSql2012Dialect.cs, include it in your project and reference it (adding the correct assembly name).

Comment: There is one issue: the source code of this MsSql2012Dialect contains a reference to NHibernate.SqlCommand.Parser which seems to be missing from the latest v3.3.3GA. So I'm not sure if I can reuse this new MsSql2012Dialect. It seems, they have implemented some major changes in NH4 which makes it hard to reuse just a part of their code.

Comment: Good point. Then it's probably down to compiling NH from source.

Comment: I spent some hours inspecting the code and collecting the SqlParser pieces. I had to import just 3 or 4 files in my assembly to be able to compile the MsSql2012Dialect. Tomorrow we'll run some in-depth tests, but from the first glance everything seems to be fine. Thank you for leading me to the NHibernate source.

Comment: @Martin How did your custom NH work out? Would you be willing to post the source/DLL somewhere? I'm facing the same paging issue as your original post. Thanks!